# Can Roslyn execute complex scripts?

Tags: c#, roslyn, moonsharp

We have a scenario where using a scripting language will enable us to avoid coding too many client-specific custom features in our software. We've identified an area where scripting might be helpful:

1. Data Import: Here a file (text file, excel, etc.) is selected, parsed and validated against business rules and the data is then imported to the db.

In the above area, within the script we need to:

1. Access our other assemblies (eg. POCO assembly), create classes and call methods
2. Connect to a db to retrieve and write back data

Does Roslyn enable us to achieve the above or should we look into other solutions such [Moonsharp](http://www.moonsharp.org)?

Comment: I've decided against Moonsharp and used [NLua](http://nlua.org/) instead. I do think NLua is more mature, more often updated and more popular. Just compare [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=moonsharp) to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nlua).

Comment: @UweKeim I was looking at NLua too, but as Roslyn is C# we would avoid using another language.

Comment: Roslyn is the full C# compiler.  It can run all of C#, by definition.